# Flask и sqlalchemy асинхронность

Tags: flask, async-await, sqlalchemy

Есть API на Flask + sqlalchemy.
Есть задача сделать API асинхронным, соответственно отсюда нужно и запросы к БД сделать асинхронными.
Структура проекта почти стандартная, но что бы не находил в google не получается применить в проекте. Help me, please.)
За действующую консультацию готов заплатить.

1. app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import config
from flasgger import Swagger


app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '1'
app.config.from_mapping(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=config.POSTGRE_URI)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = create_engine(config.POSTGRE_URI, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
```

2. views.py

```
class ParselinksView(MethodView):
    """Получение ссылок по master id"""
    decorators = [token_required]

    @swag_from('swagger\\parselinks.yml')
    def get(self, master_product_id):
        query = ParseLinksTable.query.filter_by(master_sku_id=str(master_product_id)).distinct(ParseLinksTable.link).all()
        links = []
        for link in query:
            links.append(link.link)

        return jsonify({
            'count': len(links),
            'links': links})
```

Comment: Ну в первую очередь нужно отказаться от использования Flask, потому что он не асинхронный

Comment: @andreymal, хотя бы сделать запросы к БД асинхронными). Иначе запрос в таблицу со 160к+ записями не проходит проверку тестом wrk -t 8 -c 100 -d 10 http://172.21.160.1:5000/parselinks/100

Comment: В этом нет никакого смысла, потому что синхронный Flask всё равно будет всё синхронно блокировать, и результаты в wrk не изменятся - точнее, они даже испортятся, потому что добавятся накладные расходы на асинхронщину

Comment: Ну и да, судя по порту 5000, вы тестируете отладочный сервер, что есть полный абсурд, потому что он не затачивался на производительность. Возьмите какой-нибудь нормальный сервер - например, gunicorn или uwsgi, - поставьте воркеров/потоков побольше и проверьте wrk ещё раз

Comment: @andreymal, да, точно, спасибо.